# How to identify connected network is open or Secured in swift?

Tags: swift, networking, ios14

As per the requirement, iOS app needs to identify the currently connected networks whether its open or password protected and display an alert message to the user.

I have gone through the link below but could not make it work https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork/1618930-issecure
I have received entitlements from the apple, But could not see any sample project.

I expect the code should be similar to the below (just to make the question clear, not real code)

```
let network = NEHotspotNetwork() // get the currently connected network
        let isSecured = network.isSecure // get the current security
        print("isSecure \(isSecured)") //printing the security is password protected or not
```

Comment: I would say the problem is with `let network = NEHotspotNetwork()` because you are creating an instance of `NEHotspotNetwork` instead of fetching current connection. Did you try use `fetchCurrent(completionHandler:)` ?

Comment: Thanks it looks working , though NEHotspotNetwork nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request, but it has to work more with permissions seems

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider to achieve this

1. Request entitlement from apple
2. Your device target is iOS 14.*
3. Code below

   ```
   if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
       NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent { network in
           if let network = network {
               print("is secured \((network.isSecure))")
           }
       }
   }
   ```